# Dynamic nested *ngFor

Tags: javascript, angular

I am working on angular 5 application, I want to make a dynamic form based on the dynamic nested array of objects

```
`
[
    {
        "key": "unitName",
        "value": "DESKTOP"
    },
    {
        "key": "store",
        "value": "Lucan"
    },
    {
        "key": "app",
        "value": [
            {
                "key": "fullscreen",
                "value": true
            },
            {
                "key": "height",
                "value": 1920
            },
            {
                "key": "setPosition",
                "value": [
                    {
                        "key": "x",
                        "value": 25
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "y",
                        "value": 0
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "key": "devMode",
                "value": true
            },
            {
                "key": "disableZoom",
                "value": false
            }
        ]
    }
]
`
```

in this example, I know the array depth is 3 levels
so I can write 3 *ngFor inside each other

but what if I have more than 3 levels, I was wondering if there is a way to make it dynamic.

Comment: So you application's data model varies dynamically? How do you expect to parse this dynamic form on the server side?  The server and client models should be a reflection of each other. This is an important question, because it goes to how you would layout your interfaces in TS on the client.

Comment: Assuming the nested templates are identical you could use recursion (where the component creates another instance of itself for each nested item).

Comment: Think of it as of tree array. Make component for single leaf and then do *ngFor for a root leaves. Inside each leaf component template check for children leaves and do *ngFor for them. Kind of recursion in template.

Comment: it is json configuration file stored locally not server model @RandyCasburn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a **tree view** directive as follows:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'tree-view',
    template: `
        <div *ngFor="#obj of objs">
            <tree-view [objs]="obj.objs"></tree-view>
        <div>
    `,
    directives: [TreeView]
})
export class TreeView {
    @Input() 
    private objs: Array<any>;
}
```

There are some libraries that do that for you. For example: https://angular2-tree.readme.io/docs

Comment: I don't know who did, but thanks, your answer helped me to solve my problem.

Comment: Thanks @tareknoaman! You can also upvote the answer to make it look useful to other members.